# Inquiry re ETA visa to Australia without reference number. Is my visa valid?

Tags: visas, australia, application-status, eta

I asked a travel agency to apply an ETA visa for Australia for me. After they processed it, they gave me a note that I was approved for ETA visa. The details in the note that they gave me are expiry date, number of entries, my passport details, type of visa and status (can work or not). There was no reference number.  Is my visa valid? Need to know as soon as possible because I am leaving next week. Please answer me....thanks.

Comment: We have no more information about your ETA than you do. Your ETA is valid if your travel agent is telling you the truth, and it is invalid if they are lying to you. What more could we say?

Comment: According to this website you always get a reference number when you apply https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETAS3/etas?submit=check , maybe ask the agency

Comment: Please note that the ETA is not a visa; it's a travel authorization to allow you to go to Australia without a visa.  The effect is similar to having a visa, but if you contact Australia's ETA office and start talking about applying for a "visa" when you mean an ETA, it will lead to confusion.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 4):

On the Department of Immigration's [ETA site](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETAS3/etas), you can verify the status of your ETA (snapshot below). This form sounds like the best way to verify the validity of your ETA.

However, the form requires you to input your personal passport details, and the ETA reference number.

I recommend contacting your travel agent to request that they provide the reference number to you, then verify it using this form.

[image: Check an ETA web form]

Comment: Thanks for all your response...Do you think its wise if I will just apply one online to be on the safe side?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion... It's up to you whether you mind paying the extra $20 for the peace of mind. I would ask the travel agent for the reference number as a first step.

Comment: I check again in the australian immigration website and found the solution for my problem. You can request from vevo for your reference number. If you give them the details they are looking for and a scan or copy of your passport then they will email you with your visa grant number.